# How to provide long click listener in Kotlin in Adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, onlongclicklistener

How can I implement long click listener in Adapter? I have already implemented onClickLister by interface. But I don't know how to implement long click listener.

This is Adapter

```
class DokladAdapter(private val listener: OnItemClickListener): ListAdapter<DokladTuple, DokladAdapter.PolozkaViewHolder>(DiffCallback()) {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PolozkaViewHolder {
        val binding = DokladyItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return PolozkaViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PolozkaViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = getItem(position)
        if (currentItem != null) {
            holder.bind(currentItem)
        }
    }

    inner class PolozkaViewHolder(private val binding: DokladyItemBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        init {
            binding.root.setOnClickListener{
                val position = bindingAdapterPosition
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                    val item = getItem(position)
                    if (item != null){
                        listener.onItemClick(item)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        fun bind(polozkaHlavicka: DokladTuple){
            binding.apply {
                tvU.text = "U"
                tvDOKL.text = polozkaHlavicka.doklad.toString()
                //tvODB.text = "200"
                tvORG.text = polozkaHlavicka.odj.toString()
                tvDATUM.text = polozkaHlavicka.datuct.toString()
            }
        }
    }
    interface OnItemClickListener{
        fun onItemClick(polozkaHlavicka: DokladTuple)
    }

    class DiffCallback: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<DokladTuple>(){
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: DokladTuple, newItem: DokladTuple) =
            oldItem.doklad == newItem.doklad

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: DokladTuple, newItem: DokladTuple) =
            oldItem == newItem
    }
}
```

I have override function in Activity

```
class Activity: AppCompatActivity(), PolozkaAdapter.OnItemClickListener{
override fun onItemClick(polozkaDoklad: PolozkaTuple) {
        //TODO - do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Do it exactly the same way except use `setOnLongClickListener` instead of `setOnClickListener`. You'll need a second interface.

Comment: So in binding.root init block I can create second binding.root.setOnLongClickListener. Am I right?

Comment: Yes.................

Answer (score 8, accepted):

using Kotlin , i do it like that without adding listeners interfaces , i found it more readable an easy to use, here is my example and you can adjust it to your adapter and objects
for this example i have a Cycle object it's costume you can change it with yours
i declare two variables

```
var onItemClick: ((Cycle) -> Unit)? = null
var onItemLongClick: ((Cycle) -> Unit)?= null
```

then in the view holder

```
init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener{
                onItemClick?.invoke(cycleList[adapterPosition])
            }
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener {
            onItemLongClick?.invoke(cycleList[adapterPosition])
            return@setOnLongClickListener true
        }

    }
```

and i use it like that anywhere :

```
    cycleAdapter= CycleAdapter(cycleList)
    binding.cyclesRecyclerView.adapter=cycleAdapter
    cycleAdapter.onItemClick={
       Toast.makeText( requireContext(),it.cycleName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    cycleAdapter.onItemLongClick={
      Toast.makeText( requireContext(),it.cycleName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

"it" here stand for the clicked item object  for me it's the clicked Cycle

Comment: Don't use adapterPosition, absoluteAdapterPosition or bindingAdapterPosition in viewHolder init{} block. Position is always -1 !

Comment: That was working then , it's been almost 2 years, you can update the answer and post it on

Answer (score 2):

Update your `OnItemClickListener` to include a long click handler as

```
interface OnItemClickListener{ 
    fun onClick(polozkaHlavicka: DokladTuple)
    fun onLongClick(polozkaHlavicka: DokladTuple)
}
```

Now in `PolozkaViewHolder` `init`, add `longClickListener` as

```
binding.root.setOnLongClickListener{
    // get position data and call long click handler 
    //listener.onLongClick()
    true
}
```

finally update the implementation of `OnItemClickListener` in `Activity` for `onLongClick`

Comment: when I provide the setOnLongClickListener in binding.root init block I get an error: Type mismatch. Required: Booleanp Found: Unit. I have the same code as in setOnClickListener

Comment: setOnLongClickListener must return a boolean value, signifying if click was consumed, in your case you can return true

Comment: but where I should insert it?

Comment: I have updated the answer, simply write true in the last line of onLongClick block